# Cannot save Nvidia X settings Tweaks

Tags: nvidia, settings, gpu

I installed 16.04 today and I wanted to increase the color liveliness and tweak some vertical sync and texture quality settings, but every time I reboot the settings get reverted back.

Every guide and forum I looked around was way too complicated and didn't help me in solving my problem that seems quite simple for someone who has experience with the Linux and Nvidia GPUs.

I have changed settings from a lot of the sections and I want all of the saved every time I restart.

A quick step by step guide on what I should do would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Bring up your terminal, then run `nvidia-settings` as root:

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

After you've configured your settings, click on `X Server Display Configuration`, then click on the `Save to X Configuration File` button, enter `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in the textbox, make sure `Merge with existing file` is unchecked, then click the `Save` button.

Comment: In doing this when I go to quit it says pending changes and the configuration is not saved.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Above solution did not work for me.
Nvidia settings has a "Show Preview" button when saving.
Use this to copy-paste the contents into the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file manually.

I tried the above solution again just now, just to double check, and every time it tells me:

`Unable to open X config file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for writing.

Even told me the same for my home directory and root's home directory.

Comment: Doing this caused my computer to no longer boot because my terminal mangled the blank space when copy-pasting!